# multithreading and dynamic arrays/matrix-op's

Tags: c++, multithreading, linear-algebra, dynamic-arrays

I am currently writing a physical simulation (t.b.m.p. solving a stochastic differential equation) and I need to parallelize it.
Now this could be achieved with MPI and I think I will have to do it some time in the future, but currently I want to utilize all 8 cores of my local machine for it. A normal run takes from 2 - 17 hours for one parameter set. Therefore I thought to utilize multithreading, specifically the following function should be executed in parallel. This function essentially solves the same SDE `Nrep` times for `Nsteps` timesteps. The results are averaged and stored for each thread into a separate row of an `Nthreads x Nsteps` array `JpmArr`.

```
double **JpmArr;
void worker(const dtype gamma, const dtype dt, const uint seed, const uint Nsteps, const uint Nrep,\
            const ESpMatD& Jplus, const ESpMatD& Jminus, const ESpMatD& Jz, const uint tId ){


dtype dW(0), stdDev( sqrt(dt) );

std::normal_distribution<> WienerDistr(0, stdDev);

//create the arrays for the values of <t|J+J-|t>
 dtype* JpmExpect = JpmArr[tId];

//execute Nrep repetitions of the experiment
for (uint r(0); r < Nrep; ++r) {
    //reinitialize the wave function
    psiVecArr[tId] = globalIstate;
    //<t|J+J-|t>
    tmpVecArr[tId] = Jminus* psiVecArr[tId];
    JpmExpect[0] += tmpVecArr[tId].squaredNorm();
    //iterate over the timesteps
    for (uint s(1); s < Nsteps; ++s) {

        //get a random number
        dW = WienerDistr(RNGarr[tId]);

        //execute one step of the RK-s.o. 1 scheme
        tmpPsiVecArr[tId] = F2(gamma, std::ref(Jminus), std::ref(psiVecArr[tId]) );
        tmpVecArr[tId] = psiVecArr[tId] + tmpPsiVecArr[tId] * sqrt(dt);
        psiVecArr[tId] = psiVecArr[tId] + F1(gamma, std::ref(Jminus), std::ref(Jplus),   std::ref(psiVecArr[tId])) * dt + tmpPsiVecArr[tId] * dW \
 + 0.5 * (F2(gamma, std::ref(Jminus), std::ref(tmpVecArr[tId]) ) - F2(gamma, std::ref(Jminus), std::ref(psiVecArr[tId]))) *(dW * dW - dt) / sqrt(dt);

        //normalise
        psiVecArr[tId].normalize();
        //compute <t|J+J-|t>
        tmpVecArr[tId] = Jminus* psiVecArr[tId];
        JpmExpect[s] += tmpVecArr[tId].squaredNorm();
    }
}


//average over the repetitions
for (uint j(0); j < Nsteps; ++j) {
    JpmExpect[j] /= Nrep;
}
}
```

I am using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) as a library for linear algebra, thus:

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<dtype, Eigen::RowMajor> ESpMatD;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<dtype, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> VectorXdrm;
```

are used as types. The above worker function calls:

```
VectorXdrm& F1(const dtype a, const ESpMatD& A, const ESpMatD& B, const VectorXdrm& v) {
z.setZero(v.size());
y.setZero(v.size());

// z is for simplification
z = A*v;

//scalar intermediate value c = <v, Av>
dtype c = v.dot(z);

y = a * (2.0 * c * z - B * z - c * c * v);
return y;
}

VectorXdrm& F2(const dtype a, const ESpMatD& A, const VectorXdrm& v) {
//zero the data
z.setZero(v.size());
y.setZero(v.size());

z = A*v;

dtype c = v.dot(z);

y = sqrt(2.0 * a)*(z - c * v);
return y;
}
```

where the vectors `z,y` are of type `VectorXdrm` and are declared in the same file (module-global). 
All the arrays (`RNGarr, JpmArr, tmpPsiVecArr, tmpVecArr, psiVecArr`) are initialized in main (by use of `extern` declaration in `main.cpp`). After that setup is done I run the function using `std::async`, wait for all to finish and then collect the data from `JpmArr` into a single array in `main()` and write it to file.

**Problem:**
The results are nonsense if I use `std::launch::async`. 
If I use `std::launch::deferred` the computed and averaged results match (as far as then numerical method permits) the results I obtain by analytic means.

I have no idea anymore where stuff fails. I used to use Armadillo for linear algebra, but it's `normalize` routine delivered `nan`'s so I switched to Eigen, which hints (in the documenation) at being usable with multiple threads - it still fails.
Having not worked with threads before I have spent 4 days now trying to get this working and reading up on things. The latter lead me to use the global arrays `RNGarr, JpmArr, tmpPsiVecArr, tmpVecArr, psiVecArr` (before I just tried to create the appropriate arrays in `worker` and pass the results by means of a `struct workerResult` back to main.) as well as using `std::ref()` to pass the matrices `Jplus, Jminus, Jz` to the function.(the last is omitted in the function above - for brevity)

But the results I get are still wrong and I have no Idea anymore, what is wrong and what I should do to get the right results.
Any input and/or pointers to examples of solutions of such (threading) problems or references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code which does the actual call to launch::async?   Key requirement for being able to run multiple threads is that all code should be thread safe (which is hard to determine, but change of being true in C++ is better than in C), and that each thread should work on its  own datastructure (or some programatic guarantee of that they are not stepping on each others toes)

Comment: `auto ws = std::async(std::launch::deferred, &worker, gamma, dt, RNGseed[s], Nsteps, NrepPt, std::ref(Jplus), std::ref(Jminus), std::ref(Jz), tId++);` where `s` is 0,1,2,3 set manually for now

Comment: Jplus, Jminus -- they are references to other matrixis?   Would they be updated by another thread while the worker is running?

Comment: Both are sparse Eigen matrices in CSR format. They are created in `main()` then passed by reference to each of the threads as in the call above. As each thread executes only `worker` and there only MVM takes place these matrices should not be modified - but I will check that.

Comment: Do you ever actually allocate memory for `JmpArr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is clearly some interaction between the calculations in each thread -- either due to that your global data is being updated by multiple thread, or though some of the structures passed by reference is mutating while running -- `z` and `y` cannot be globals if they are updated by multiple threads -- but there may be many other problems

I would suggest you refactor the code as follows;

- Make it object oriented -- define a class which are self contained.   Take all the parameters which are given to worker and make them members of the class.
- if you are not sure if data structures are mutating, then do not pass them by reference.  If in doubt assume the worst and make complete copies within the class.
- In cases where threads do have to update shared structures (you should have none in your use case) you will need to protect read and writes by mutexes for exclusive access.
- Remove all global -- instead of having a global `JpmArr`, `z` and `y`, define the data which is needed within the class.
- make `worker`, `F1`, `F2` member functions of your class.

Then in main, `new` your newly created class as many times as you need, and start each of them as a thread -- making sure that you are waiting for the thread to complete before you read any of the data -- each thread will have its own stack, and its own data within the class, and hence interference between parallel calculations becomes much less likely.

If you want to optimize further, you will need to consider each matrix calculation as a `job` and create a pool of thread matching the number of cores and let each thread pick up a job sequentially, that will reduce context switching overhead and CPU L1/L2 cache misses which will happen if your number of threads becomes many more than your number of cores -- however this is becoming a lot more elaborate than what you need for your immediate problem....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into them over the WE. As an aside, I was sure the matrices should not be modified (and they are not) therefore I passed them in by ref. Further optimizations will have to wait until this is verified as working.

Comment: After I rewrote the code as you suggested everything works fine and is easily modifiable. Many thanks for that. As for performance optimizations any further input is welcome. Currently I use as many threads as CPUs for my calculations with `g++` flags `-2 -msse2 -msse4.1 -mtune=core2` for my system, but the serious runs still take more than a day (and there is still code to be added)

Answer (score 0):

Stop using globals. It's bad style anyway, and here multiple threads will be zeroing and mutating `z` and `y` at the same time.

The simplest fix is to replace your globals with local variables in the worker function - so each concurrent call to worker has its own copy - and pass them into `F1` and `F2` by reference.

Comment: My thought was, that this would be a bad Idea b/c the variables in this case are vectors and because, as I understand it, all threads share a heap this would not be a good idea. Anyways, this code has gone through many mutations (not listed in the original post for brevity). Both variables(vectors) were local (static and non-static) up to the current iteration of the modifications to the code - without any positive effect on the solution.

Comment: Using local variables in worker should be fine. Doing lots of dynamic heap (de)allocation in multiple threads may perform poorly, because the shared heap has to be synchronized, but there's no problem with correctness. Anyway, I think you're saying that you tried some other code and got the same problem? Unless you can show a complete, self-contained program that reproduces this, no-one can guess what might have gone wrong in other versions of your incomplete code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I have now declared `z,y` local to the functions `F1,F2` and changed both functions to return a copy of 'y'. The results seem to match the predictions now.